read data in spark dataframe based on schema but be case insensitive
I have set "spark.sql.caseSensitive","False" in spark conf.
This is how I am creating the schema:
schema = {
    "type": "struct",
    "fields": [
        {"metadata": {}, "name": "firstName", "nullable": True, "type": "string"},
        {"metadata": {}, "name": "address", "nullable": True, "type": {
            "type": "struct",
            "fields": 
            [
                {"metadata": {}, "name": "addressline1", "nullable": True, "type": "string"},
                {"metadata": {}, "name": "addressline2", "nullable": True, "type": "string"}
            ]}
        }
        
    ]
}

this is what my data looks like:
data = [
    {
        "name":"some name 1",
        "address": {
            "addressLine1": "some address line 1",
            "addressLine2": "some address line 2"
        }
    }
]

this is how I am creating dataframe:
schema_as_json = StructType.fromJson(schema)

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema_as_json)

this does not read data from addressline1 and addressline2 as they are in different case. (Notice L)
I have no control over the data so I cannot change the column names to be lowercase.
How do I read the data from the given input and still keep the field names in schema lowercase?
If I change addressline1 to addressLine1 and addressline2 to addressLine2, it reads the data correctly but then when I try to merge the data in the Iceberg table, it throws me an error saying

AnalysisException saying Could not align Iceberg MERGE INTO


"I have no control over the data so I cannot change the column names to be lowercase." - What do you mean when you say "cannot change the column names"? I assume as long as you can read the data - you can for sure create a new dataframe with the new column names right? Am I missing something?

i cannot change the column names in data as thats what comes from upstream systems. i would like to avoid creating new dataframe if possible and see if there is a way i can do this by asking spark to be not case sensitive when reading the data.

The next step is convert your schema to upper case.
scol = [col_upper_convert(col) for col in df.schema.fieldNames()]
df = df.toDF(*scol)

That solves your issue. Also, compare your table schema and df schema before write.

Even with spark.sql.caseSensitive set to False, the schema must match the data structure exactly( As the PySpark documentation shows, this configuration applies to only Spark SQL).
The simple way is to transform the schema dynamically without modifying the data. Here is the working code.
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

 
schema = StructType([
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("address", StructType([
        StructField("addressline1", StringType(), True),
        StructField("addressline2", StringType(), True)
    ]), True)
])

 
data = [
    {
        "name": "some name 1",
        "address": {
            "addressLine1": "some address line 1",
            "addressLine2": "some address line 2"
        }
    }
]

 def transform_keys(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {k.lower(): transform_keys(v) for k, v in obj.items()}
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return [transform_keys(i) for i in obj]
    return obj

 transformed_data = [transform_keys(record) for record in data]

 
df = spark.createDataFrame(transformed_data, schema)
 
df.show(truncate=False)

Please let me know if you need more information.

doing this at record level will loop thru millions of records. i would rather create a new dataframe with the schema with lowercase keys.

The other way round is just convert schema to upper case. It is one time activity and create new df
